# CentOS does not access internet, unless by manually changing the adapters to NAT and Host Only

Tags: linux, centos, localhost, virtualbox, virtualhost

I have the below dev. environment.

- **Hardware:-**  Windows 7, 32bit, HP Laptop.
- **Software:-**  CentOs 6.5 running on VirtualBox 4.3.10.

**In a nutshell** The problem is that I can't access the internet and localhost at the same time in my VirtualBox. Example:

### HOST ONLY ADAPTER

If I have my VirtualBox adapter set to **Host Only**. `ifconfig eth0` shows me the below configuration:

```
#ifconfig eth0
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:81:0F:EA
inet addr:192.168.57.162  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe81:fea/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:342 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:37176 (36.3 KiB)  TX bytes:66580 (65.0 KiB)
```

And `cat /etc/resolv.conf` shows the below:

```
#cat /etc/resolv.conf
[root@localhost ethio360.com]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
nameserver 212.98.41.104
nameserver 194.290.66.07
```

Now, with those above settings. If I check `http://192.168.57.162` I can see all is working. Nginx, Php ... all is fine. The problem here is that, if I wanted to install a package with `yum install ...` or `yum update` or even `ping google.co.uk` gives me error. Example:

```
[root@localhost myProject]# ping google.co.uk
ping: unknown host google.co.uk
```

So, I tried to switch to NAT Adapter.

### NAT ADAPTER

Now, with NAT. I if I do `ifconfig eth0` I see the below config:

```
 #ifconfig
Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:81:0F:EA
inet addr:10.0.2.15 Bcast:10.0.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr:fe80::a00:27ff:fe81:fea/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX pacakets:434 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
TX Packets:445 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:47366 (46.2 KiB TX bytes:76674 (74.8Kib)
```

Now, you would assume if I typed `10.0.2.15`, `127.0.0.1`, `localhost` or even `http://10.0.2.15`  I would be able to see my server running or my web pages. But, No! Nothing shows up. I get an error message, as if I was trying to access a page that did not exist. I've even adjusted my hosts file. But nothing. I can't even access CentOs using putty. But, weird enough I can install packages, ping server and all..

So, I tried to use two adapters, but sadly whichever is set Adpater 1 only seems to work, as if the Adapter 2 is being ignored. So, overall with these settings, I can either only install packages but not see my server, or vise versa.

I am looking for alternative that will allow me to see my localhost and install pacakges at the same time using only one adapter.

Comment: I think this question might get better and more enthusiastic response in SuperUser (http://superuser.com/) as it is not a programming question for which StackOverflow is dedicated. You can use your StackOverflow account in SuperUser as well.

Comment: The question is answered here on superuser: 
http://superuser.com/questions/738196/unable-to-access-localhost-internet-using-one-adapter-in-centos/738389?noredirect=1#comment949284_738389